# How to retrive last updated record from oracle data base?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to retrieve the last 20 rows that have been updated from a table in an Oracle database without using order by 
then rownum function like

```
select * 
  from EMP 
 order by last_Updated 
 where rownum < 20
```

This query takes lot of time.

Comment: Please post a table definition including any indexes on the table, you are probably just missing one on the last_Updated field

Comment: A ROWNUM value is assigned to a row after it passes the predicate phase of the query but BEFORE the query does any sorting or aggregation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you posted doesn't do what you think it does.  That query will fetch 20 arbitrary rows and then order by the `last_updated` column.  If you want the 20 most recent rows, you'd need to `ORDER BY last_updated` in a nested query and then apply the `rownum` predicate in an outer query.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM emp
         ORDER BY last_updated desc)
 WHERE rownum <= 20
```

Assuming that `last_updated` is indexed, that should be a very efficient query.  You should be able to do a min/max scan on the `last_updated` index and then do a `count stopkey` to fetch only the first 20 rows.  If you are having problems with the performance of this query, what sort of query plan are you getting?

Comment: Thanks Justin, may I want accurate enough but my problem not in retrieving data, the problem is the query time ... 
your query is true but takes much time to execute. 
My Question is is there is any way to do this with less query time ?

Comment: @Manaysah - As I said in my answer, if you have a performance problem when running this query, please show us the query plan.  Is `last_updated` indexed?  Is the query using the index?

Comment: Thanks, the issue solved using the Same Query, but the problem were in database connection which slows the query time.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Rownum() instead and order by update_date desc where rownum() <=20...

Comment: Thanks Art, 
but the problem of query time will still exist because the query will take more time to sort all result which are very huge, then to select 20 records.
I want a method which will enhance the query execution with less time.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm afraid you cannot avoid sorting and using rownum or rownum() in your case. And it is hard to suggest smth. w/out seeing and trying it on real data.